# How do I include tags in the new @sentry/node API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sentry

Before '@sentry/node' was released, I used the raven module. Including tags with all of my errors was as simple as including a tags property in the options object when configuring Raven.

```
Raven.config(DSN, {
  tags: {...}
})
```

How do I include tags when using the new API? So far I've tried:

```
Sentry.init({
    dsn: DSN,
    tags: {
        process_name: 'webserver',
    },
})
```

and

```
Sentry.configureScope(scope => {
    scope.setTag('process_name', 'webserver')
})
```

but neither attempt works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to use `Sentry.configureScope`, but as mentioned in the [sdk docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sentry/node) `Note that these functions will not perform any action before you have called init()`.

This should work, otherwise you would have to contact sentry:

```
const Sentry = require('@sentry/node');

Sentry.init({
  dsn: '__DSN__',
  // ...
});

Sentry.configureScope(scope => {
  scope.setExtra('battery', 0.7);
  scope.setTag('user_mode', 'admin');
  scope.setUser({ id: '4711' });
  // scope.clear();
});
```

Comment: Looks like this was a bug that has been fixed: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/1632

Comment: @Sam that's great!

Answer (score 3):

According to [docs](https://docs.sentry.io/enriching-error-data/scopes/?platform=javascript)

You can use `Sentry.configureScope` to configure scope, which including tag, of a Sentry instance.

```
Sentry.configureScope((scope) => {
  scope.setTag("my-tag", "my value");
  scope.setUser({
    id: 42,
    email: "john.doe@example.com"
  });
});
```

Or you can use `Sentry.withScope` if you only want to send data with one specific event.

```
Sentry.withScope(scope => {
  scope.setTag("my-tag", "my value");
  scope.setLevel('warning');
  // will be tagged with my-tag="my value"
  Sentry.captureException(new Error('my error'));
});

// will not be tagged with my-tag
Sentry.captureException(new Error('my other error'));
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me a lot!